# how to find instances of elements of a factor vector in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a factor vector called Categories with 47 levels

```
Categories = as.factor(sort(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 47), sep='')))

[1] a  a1 b  b1 c  c1 d  d1 e  e1 f  f1 g  g1 h  h1 i  i1 j  j1 k  k1 l  l1 m  m1 n  n1 o  o1 p  p1 q  q1 r  r1 s  s1 t 
[40] t1 u  u1 v  w  x  y  z 
47 Levels: a a1 b b1 c c1 d d1 e e1 f f1 g g1 h h1 i i1 j j1 k k1 l l1 m m1 n n1 o o1 p p1 q q1 r r1 s s1 t t1 u u1 ... z
```

I have another vector called cat with 9 of those levels

```
cat = Categories[c(7,42,43,24,45,26,35,6,15)]
[1] d  u1 v  l1 x  m1 r  c1 h 
47 Levels: a a1 b b1 c c1 d d1 e e1 f f1 g g1 h h1 i i1 j j1 k k1 l l1 m m1 n n1 o o1 p p1 q q1 r r1 s s1 t t1 u u1 ... z
```

I also have a dataframe My_Data with 36 rows. One of the columns in the dataframe has multiple occurences of the values from cat

```
My_Data = data.frame(name = make.unique(rep(c(1:10,LETTERS), length.out = 36), sep=''), cat = sample(rep(cat,4),36,replace = FALSE), position = 0)

    name cat position
1     1   v        0
2     2   r        0
3     3   h        0
4     4  m1        0
5     5   h        0
6     6  u1        0
7     7  l1        0
8     8   h        0
9     9  u1        0
10   10   x        0
11    A   x        0
12    B   v        0
13    C   d        0
14    D  c1        0
15    E   r        0
16    F   v        0
17    G  l1        0
18    H   d        0
19    I  l1        0
20    J  c1        0
21    K  u1        0
22    L   x        0
23    M   v        0
24    N   d        0
25    O  l1        0
26    P  m1        0
27    Q   r        0
28    R  m1        0
29    S   h        0
30    T  m1        0
31    U  c1        0
32    V   d        0
33    W   r        0
34    X   x        0
35    Y  c1        0
36    Z  u1        0
```

I want to fill the position column of the dataframe with the occurence number of the particular value of cat. So, the first 15 rows would like:

```
     name cat position
1     1   v        1
2     2   r        1
3     3   h        1
4     4  m1        1
5     5   h        2
6     6  u1        1
7     7  l1        1
8     8   h        3
9     9  u1        2
10   10   x        1
11    A   x        2
12    B   v        2
13    C   d        1
14    D  c1        1
15    E   r        2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean like this `transform(My_Data, position = ave(as.character(cat), cat, FUN = seq_along))`? Your description is not very clear imo.

Comment: Thanks! This method seems to work for the sample dataset I have created here but not for my actual dataset. I get the following error:

`Warning messages:
1: In split.default(x, g) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In split.default(seq_along(x), f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable`

1. What do you think is the issue here?
2. How do you think the question is confusing and what can I do to improve the question?

Comment: Ok. Not getting the error anymore. I was doing something wrong. Thanks! I found this to be the best solution. If you can include this as an answer, I can accept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform(My_Data, position = ave(as.character(cat), cat, FUN = seq_along))
```

This answer is attributed to [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `group_by` and `mutate` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

Categories = as.factor(sort(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 47), sep='')))
cat = Categories[c(7,42,43,24,45,26,35,6,15)]

My_Data = 
  data.frame(name = make.unique(rep(c(1:10,LETTERS), length.out = 36), sep=''), 
             cat = sample(rep(cat,4),36,replace = FALSE), 
             position = 0) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  mutate(position = 1:n())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `group_by` and `row_number` from the `dplyr` package.

```
My_Data2 <- My_Data %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(position = row_number())
```